# MATRIZ EN JAVASCRIPT HECHA POR EL USUARIO

Tags: javascript, html

necesito saber como hacer una matriz cuya columna y filas sean digitadas por el usuario, no entiendo muy bien la sintaxis de la matriz, solo tengo entendido que se hace declarando dos vectores, pero no se de que manera.

Comment: Hola Juan, para que te podamos ayudar debes indicarnos el código que has intentado. Si nos pones la sintaxis que no entiendes podremos explicartela.

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Hola JUAN DAVID, si tienes una nueva pregunta, debes crear una nueva publicación en lugar de editar la publicación anterior y cambiarla (ten en cuenta que al hacer eso, las respuestas dejan de tener sentido). Visita el [tour] y lee sobre [ask] para más información.

Answer (score 1):

`m` es tu numero de filas:

```
let m = parseInt(prompt("digite el numero de filas"))
```

`n` es tu numero de columnas:

```
let n = parseInt(prompt("digite el numero de columnas"))
```

Ambas las digita el usuario.

```
let t = 0
```

No se si te refieres con `t` a la cantidad de filas y de columnas que hay en total en la matriz sumada. en cuyo caso esto es simplemente calculable multiplicando el total de columnas por el total de filas.

Deseas crear una matriz `bidimensional` por lo que tengo entendido, así que tu ya tienes cuantas columnas quieres (`m`) y cuantas filas quieres (`n`), lo unico que debes hacer es crear una matriz con las dimensiones `m` y `n` o `m` x `n`.

Recordemos que en un array las filas siempre van primero y las columnas van despues:

```
[filas][columnas]
```

Asi que si tenemos esto:

```
array[0][2];
```

Estaríamos accediendo a la fila 1 columna 3 (porque los arreglos o matrices siempre empiezan en 0).

Entonces creemos tu arreglo:

```js
let m = parseInt(prompt("digite el numero de filas"))
let n = parseInt(prompt("digite el numero de columnas"))
let t = 0

const arregloDinamico = new Array(m).fill(new Array(n));
console.log(arregloDinamico);
```

El snippet no muestra bien el resultado, puesto que las columnas no han sido iniciadas con ningun valor.

Hay que tener en cuenta que en javascript existe esta forma de declarar un nuevo array o matriz:

```
new Array(m)
```

La cual lo que hará es limitar la cantidad de espacios en memoria que va a tener el array, en este caso esta limitado a `m` espacios en memoria, ademas, al declarar los espacios de una vez podemos usar el metodo `fill` de los arrays.

Que lo que hara es llenar cada espacio en memoria de nuestro array con algo que le indiquemos, en este caso otro array (que serán las columnas de cada fila):

```
new Array(m).fill(new Array(n));
```

Ya tenemos nuestro array con la cantidad necesarias de filas y columnas, y es asi de sencillo declararlas...

Entonces tu codigo quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```js
let m = parseInt(prompt("digite el numero de filas"))
let n = parseInt(prompt("digite el numero de columnas"))

//Asumo que querias contar la cantidad de filas y columnas que hay en total.
let t = m * n
const array = new Array(m).fill(new Array(n))

//Otra forma seria usar la propiedad length de los arrays:
//let t = array.length * array[0].length

//Recorremos las filas
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  
  //Recorremos la columna en la fila actual
  for(let j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
  
    //Asignamos un valor a la columna de nuestro array:
    array[i][j] = i + j + 1;
    
    //Imprimimos la columna actual.
    document.write(array[i][j] + " ");
  }
  
  document.write("<br>");
  
}

console.log(`El tamaño del array es de: ${m} x ${n} = ${m * n}`);
```

Comment: muchas gracias bro

Comment: De nada amigo, recuerda que si la respuesta te fue de ayuda puedes darla como aceptada dándole al botón que parece un chulo ;3